# Using only the Dedekind's theorem prove that $\forall a > 0 \exists \sqrt[n]{a}$ where $n$ is a positive integer.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Using only the Dedekind's theorem prove that $\forall a > 0 \exists \sqrt[n]{a}$ where $n$ is a positive integer.

I tried to divide the whole set of real numbers into two subsets: $$A = \{a:\forall n\in \mathbb{N}\; \exists \sqrt[n]{a}\}$$
$$B=\{b: b\notin A\}$$

Now, based on the theorem, there exists the biggest member of set $B$ or the smallest member of set $A$. Since real numbers are dense, we can find an infinitely small number in set $A$ which is still greater than $0$, therefore this is not the case. Therefore, there exists a number $b_0 = \inf(A)$.  Which caters for all positive numbers arbitrarily close to $0$. As for big numbers, set $A$ has no supremum. 

Is my proof correct? What should I change?

Comment: I doubt you will be able to prove the result in this way. Your application of Dedekind's theorem is not correct because you have not verified all the hypotheses. Please check the statement of the theorem.

Comment: Excuse me, but I don't understand what hypotheses you are referring to.

Comment: Can you write down the complete statement of Dedekind's theorem?

Comment: If we divide the set of real numbers into two parts A and B so that every element in A is smaller than every element in B, then there exists either the smallest number in set B or the greatest number in set A. This is what my book says.

Comment: So you need to verify the hypothesis: "every element in A is smaller than every element in B"

Comment: I think I did, It is explicitly stated in the problem that a is positive and it has to work for all n-s, therefore, we have no negative numbers in A.

Comment: What you say in that last comment is that for all $a$ in $A$, you have $a>0$. That is very different from the assumption you need to verify in order to apply Dedekind's theorem.

Comment: The n-th root for all possible natural numbers $n$ is only defined for arguments greater than zero. Therefore, all elements in $A$ are greater than zero. Set B is the set of objects which do not belong to set A - they are therefore smaller than or equal 0. And so all elements in B are smaller than all elements in A.

Comment: Now that you've said that, I have to admit that I do not understand what you're trying to prove. From my understanding, you want to prove that "$\forall n\in\mathbb N,\ n>0,\ \forall a\in\mathbb R,\ a>0,\ \exists x\in\mathbb R$ such that $x^n=a$". In other word, I thought you wanted to prove the existence of the $n$-th root of $a$, for any $n$ and $a$. So you can't use the fact that the $n$-th root exists in your proof. If I misunderstood what you're trying to do, could you clarify for me?

Comment: To say it differently, you said that "$\forall a\in A,\ a>0$". From there, you then go on to say that "$\forall b\in B,\ b\le 0$" *because* $b\notin A$. Except that "not belonging to $A$" does not mean "not being positive". There could be positive numbers that do not belong to $A$, thus they would belong to $B$.

Comment: From what you have written, can I say that $x^n = a^n$, and therefore, if it is supposed to hold for both, even and odd numbers, $x = a$?

Comment: Please do not write symbols unless they are essential. You end up obscuring the meaning of what you intend to say, and people have to decode it for you. For example, saying $\exists \sqrt[n]{a}$ is formally incorrect, that is not how quantifiers are used.

Comment: I wrote $x^n=a$ to "characterize" the $n$-th root of $a$, because I have no clue how you define the $n$-th root of $a$ in the context you're presenting here. From the definition I am used to, we don't have to prove existence through Dedekind's theorem. Then, what is it that you denote by $\sqrt[n]{a}$? 
Regarding your question, if you have $x^n=a^n$ for $n=1$, which is odd, then you immediately have $x=a$. So I'm not too sure what your question was.